# console torrent client alternative to rtorrent

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

Because of bug (some torrent can't be downloaded - error "Tracker group list not a list") in rtorrent i'm searching for alternatives. I need torrent client with good and intuitive console interface (in ncurser i think) like rtorrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's neither as intuitive as rtorrent nor as fast/efficient (by far), but running Azureus/Vuze with the `--ui=console` option can work reasonably well.

There are lots of plugins that allow you to remotely administer the program, though, like [AzSMRC](http://azsmrc.sourceforge.net/) (a rather complete plugin/client interface written in Java) or [HTML WebUI](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/plugin_details.php?plugin=azhtmlwebui), which is more convenient (doesn't require a locally installed program), but doesn't give you access to all the Azureus settings and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Deluge has a daemon service now too that can be controlled from webui/cli or even another deluge install : http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient